# CUDA - unexpected result with float array

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I faced an issue I do not understand. I am trying to set values of an array in the device. With int array I am doing this this way:

```
#define VECTOR_SIZE 8
int main()
{
    printf("Start\n");
    int *input_d;
    int *output_d;
    int output_h[VECTOR_SIZE];
    int input_h[VECTOR_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int size = VECTOR_SIZE*sizeof(int);
    cudaMalloc(&input_d,size);
    cudaMalloc(&output_d,size);
    cudaMemcpy(input_d,input_h,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,VECTOR_SIZE>>>(input_d,output_d);
    cudaMemcpy(output_h,output_d,size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(input_d);
    cudaFree(output_d);
    return 0;
}
```

The kernel looks like:

```
__global__ void kernel(int* input, int* output)
{
    int dx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
    output[dx] = dx;
}
```

The output (output_h) is just like I expected {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. Now when I am trying do the same on float array:

```
#define VECTOR_SIZE 8
int main()
{
    printf("Start\n");
    float *input_d;
    float *output_d;
    float output_h[VECTOR_SIZE];
    float input_h[VECTOR_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int size = VECTOR_SIZE*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&input_d,size);
    cudaMalloc(&output_d,size);
    cudaMemcpy(input_d,input_h,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,VECTOR_SIZE>>>(input_d,output_d);
    cudaMemcpy(output_h,output_d,size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(input_d);
    cudaFree(output_d);
    return 0;
}
```

with kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(float* input, float* output)
{
    int dx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
    output[dx] = dx;
}
```

I am receiving zero array on the device in output_h variable.

The full code for handling float arrays:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 8

__global__ void kernel(float* input, float* output)//, int halfSize)
{
    int dx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
    output[dx] = dx;
} 

int main()
{
    printf("Start\n");
    float *input_d;
    float *output_d;
    float output_h[VECTOR_SIZE];
    float input_h[VECTOR_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; 
    int size = VECTOR_SIZE*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&input_d,size);
    cudaMalloc(&output_d,size);
    cudaMemcpy(input_d,input_h,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,VECTOR_SIZE>>>(input_d,output_d);
    cudaMemcpy(output_h,output_d,size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(input_d);
    cudaFree(output_d);
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", output_h[i-1]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The kernel code you have shown won't even compile, so I am not sure how you expect we can comment on what the output will be or why it doesn't work as you expect. Please post the *actual* kernel code you are running.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the code and I erased one line in kernel that count the dx index. I corrected this. Thank you.

Comment: Once again. Please post complete, compilable code. Neither version of the kernel compiles (dx isn't defined anywhere) and there are missing details in the host code (what is VECTOR_SIZE? How are you inspecting the output from the kernel?). If you can't post real code, there is no point to this question, and it should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Done. I am sorry about that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the float version of the code. Are you sure there isn't something you aren't telling us? You haven't mentioned how you are determining that float version output is incorrect. Is there a loop printing out the results in the *actual* code? Does it use printf? Are you changing the format string? It would have been incredibly simple to post the actual,version of the code you are having problems with, yet for some reason you seem unwilling to do so. We can't help you if you won't help us...

Comment: I posted the code 'as it is'. I thought it would be easier to find my mistake in simplified code. Sorry. I hope now somebody would be able to find an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the integer and floating point versions of CUDA code you have posted work perfectly. The only mistake is how you are printing out the values returned by the kernel in the case of the floating point code:

```
int i;
for (i=1; i<=VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%d, ", output_h[i-1]);
}
```

should be changed to

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%f, ", output_h[i]);
}
```

(note that the `%f` format is required for printing floating point numbers).

Given that CUDA uses a C++ compiler for host code by default, you should probably prefer `iostream` to `printf` - it will work irrespective of the type of the output and not cause the error you are seeing. If I were to write a "universal" version of your example it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel(T* output)
{
    int dx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
    output[dx] = dx;
}

template<typename T, int VECTOR_SIZE>
void do_run(void)
{
    T *output_d;
    T output_h[VECTOR_SIZE] = { 999 };
    size_t size = sizeof(output_h);
    cudaMalloc(&output_d,size);
    kernel<T><<<1,VECTOR_SIZE>>>(output_d);
    cudaMemcpy(output_h, output_d, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0; i<VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
        std::cout << output_h[i] << std::endl;

    cudaFree(output_d);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Integer version" << std::endl;
    do_run<int, 8>();

    std::cout << "floating point version" << std::endl;
    do_run<float, 8>();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the output code can be used unchanged for both `int`  and `float` versions, eliminating the possibility of the mistake you made here.

Comment: Thank you! I have spent two days on that few line of code trying to figure it out what is wrong. I was convinced that there is something wrong with the kernel or array size... Once again: thank you very much!